# Custom package is uninstallable

Tags: apt, package-management, packaging

I have a custom package I've built, `python-amqplib`, which relies on python >= 2.5. I'm using repoman to push to my repo via Jenkins, which reports the build was pushed successfully. After an `apt-get update` it shows when I run `apt-cache search python-amqplib`.

However, I can't install it nor does anything show up when I run `apt-cache show python-amqplib`.

Here's what it spits out when I try to install it:

```
# apt-get install python-ampqlib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-ampqlib is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package python-ampqlib has no installation candidate
```

Here's what `apt-cache policy` shows:

```
# apt-cache policy python-amqplib
python-amqplib:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.2-4-4
  Version table:
     1.0.2-4-4 0
        500 http://apt01.my-server.com/ mycompany-staging/main Packages
     0.6.1-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe Packages
```

Answer (score 1):

From your command above there appears to be a *PQ* - *QP* mismatch in the spelling, is that just a paste typo?

Is it the case that Apt is set to always prefer lucid? (Is does not appear as such from the apt-cache output though...) Does:

```
apt-get -t mycompany-staging install {python-ampqlib,python-amqplib}
```

make any difference?